# Am I able to complement a virtual function of subclasses?

Tags: c++, function, virtual

i have a question. Lets say i have this virtual function in main class:

```
virtual void h_w() { cout << "Hello, wolrd!" << endl; }
```

And Im doing with the same function that:

```
void h_w() { cout << "Today is: " << math.rand(); << endl; }
```

Am I allowed to do that? I mean, can i change body of main function like I want in subclasses? Thanks.

Comment: Search your favorite reference for "virtual function example", which should answer your question.

Comment: Your question is unclear show a complete example please.

Comment: yes that is what polymorphism is about

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean you want something like this:

```
class base { 
public:
    virtual void h_w() { std::cout << "Hello world!\n"; }
};

class derived : public base { 
public:
    void h_w() { std::cout << "Today is: " << rand() << "\n"; }
};

int main() { 
    std::unique_ptr<base> b = std::make_unique<derived>();

    b->h_w();
}
```

...then yes, C++ supports that. In fact, this is pretty much a canonical demonstration of virtual functions, at least if you change names to (for example) "animal" as the base class and "duck" as the derived class, and have them print out something like "generic animal" and "duck" respectively. For the record, it's probably worth noting that most example based on animals are more or less broken in various ways, such as animals simply not following simple sets of rules like we expect code to.

A better example, would be something like a base class defining a generic interface to a database that allows things like reading a record, writing a record, and finding a set of records that satisfy some criteria. The derived class could then (for example) provide an implementation to carry out those "commands" in terms of some specific type of database--perhaps SQL, or perhaps some simple key/value storage engine, but the client doesn't know or care, beyond minor details like performance.

As to why this is better: first of all, because it corresponds much more closely to things you're likely to really do with a computer. Second, because we can define databases to really follow our rules and fulfill the obligations we set. With animals, we're stuck with all sorts of exceptions to any meaningful rule we might try to make, as well as the simple fact that (of course) being able to make a `Duck` say "quack" and a dog say "bow wow" isn't really very useful (and in the rare case that it is useful, we probably just want to save/retrieve its sound as some sort of blob, not define an entire new type to encode something better stored as data).

Comment: How much do I hate an animal example... It is so wrong on so many levels.

Comment: @SergeyA: It *is* terrible in many ways, but it seems to be extremely widespread anyway.

Comment: @sergey a vertibrate like you would object.

Comment: @Yakk, oh, us pesky vertibrates :D

Comment: Jerry, agreed 100%. Your edit with an SQL database is a much more welcome example.